# Change the color of the Recycler view item and return to the original state in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-databinding

I have a Recycler view to display a custom calendar and everything works fine
My problem is: when I click on one item, the color of the item changes, **but when I click on another item, the previous item does not return to default.**

my code :

```
class CalendarAdapter(val clickListener: (CalendarModel) -> Unit) :
    ListAdapter<CalendarModel, CalendarAdapter.CalendarViewHolder>(CalendarDiffUtils()) {
private var select = -1

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CalendarViewHolder {
    val binding =
        CalendarItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
    return CalendarViewHolder(binding, binding.root)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CalendarViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.onBind(getItem(position))


}

override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    return position
}


inner class CalendarViewHolder(
    private val binding: CalendarItemBinding,
    containerView: View
) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(containerView) {


    fun onBind(dateModel: CalendarModel) {
        with(dateModel) {
            with(binding) {
                //Show empty days.
                txtIranianDate.isVisible = iranianDay != EMPTY_DATE
                txtGregorianDate.isVisible = iranianDay != EMPTY_DATE
                if (iranianDay == EMPTY_DATE) {
                    return
                }


                //Click
                itemView.setOnClickListener {
                    clickListener(dateModel)


                    select = adapterPosition                // <== select:Int = -1
                    //Change color With click
                    if (select == adapterPosition){         // <== Here I want change color.
                        cardDays.setCardBackgroundColor(
                            ContextCompat.getColor(
                                itemView.context,
                                R.color.blue
                            )
                        )
                    }else{                                  // <== back to the default color.
                        cardDays.setCardBackgroundColor(
                            ContextCompat.getColor(
                                itemView.context,
                                R.color.white
                            )
                        )
                    }
```

I have removed the additional codes related to the DiffUtils classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this issue and from what I thought was very simple, the way was that after clicking, we put the position adapter in the `private var select = -1` value and use `notifyDataSetChanged()` inside the click block and We will change the color of the item **outside the click block**, pay attention to the code :

```
class CalendarAdapter(val clickListener: (CalendarModel) -> Unit) :
    ListAdapter<CalendarModel, CalendarAdapter.CalendarViewHolder>(CalendarDiffUtils()) {
    private lateinit var context: Context
    private var selectedItem = -1
//-----
other

//-----

inner class CalendarViewHolder(private val binding: CalendarItemBinding, containerView: View) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(containerView) {



    fun onBind(dateModel: CalendarModel) {
        with(dateModel) {
            with(binding) {
                txtIranianDate.isVisible = iranianDay != EMPTY_DATE
                txtGregorianDate.isVisible = iranianDay != EMPTY_DATE
                if (iranianDay == EMPTY_DATE) {
                    return
                }

                //Click
                itemView.setOnClickListener {
                    clickListener(dateModel)
                    selectedItem = adapterPosition
                    notifyDataSetChanged()
                }

                //Change color item clicked <-- Do this operation outside the click block
                   if (selectedItem == adapterPosition) {
                    cardDays.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_click_item_calendar)
                } else {
                    cardDays.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_item_calendar)
                }

               //other-------
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this isn't working is that you only change it to blue when an item is clicked, but there's no way to ever change it back because you are only changing it back in the click listener. Also, views are recycled, so each time something scrolls into view, it is getting a view that may have a blue *or* white background and you're not doing anything to fix that.

For this to work, you must change the color when binding the view holder *every time*, not just inside the click listener.

There are two places you need to set the color, both inside and outside the click listener, so you should break the color change out into a function you can reuse.

Also, there is nothing in your click listener that differs based on properties of CalendarModel, so you should move it outside `onBind` into `init` so it only has to be created one time. This will help with performance.

```
inner class CalendarViewHolder(
    private val binding: CalendarItemBinding,
    containerView: View
) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(containerView) {

    init {
        itemView.setOnClickListener {
            clickListener(dateModel)
            select = adapterPosition
            updateSelectedAppearance()
        }
    }

    fun onBind(dateModel: CalendarModel) {
        with(dateModel) {
            with(binding) {
                updateSelectedAppearance() // called every time we bind

                //Show empty days.
                txtIranianDate.isVisible = iranianDay != EMPTY_DATE
                txtGregorianDate.isVisible = iranianDay != EMPTY_DATE

                /** This early return is a code smell. What are you short-circuiting?
                    You can't short circuit when binding a view holder.
                    There is no default view state because you might be getting a
                    recycled view. Anything that you change has to be changed
                    every time this function is called, even if it is just to change
                    it back to what was the default state.
                if (iranianDay == EMPTY_DATE) {
                    return
                }
                */

                // further configuration?
            }
        }
    }

    private fun updateSelectedAppearance() {
        val isSelected = select == adapterPosition
        val color = if (isSelected) R.color.blue else R.color.white
        cardDays.setCardBackgroundColor(
            ContextCompat.getColor(itemView.context, color)
        )
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and explanation of all the code and suggestions for running the program, but this solution doesn't work. And the problem still persists.

Comment: @graceful, Please edit your question to show your new version of the complete view holder class.

Comment: Thanks for your help,  I finally found it